# How to control animations inside a loop?

Tags: jquery, animation, loops, controls, queue

I want to control my loop and its animations (fadingIn/Out images) onClick. Click should stop the fadeIn/Out animation cycle and start from the desired location again. Solutions I came with are not satisfying. They make dual click hide everything and/or make instances of the loop and related glitches and so on.... Noob at work so go easy on me and help if you can.

Here is some code for the general idea, but I'll provide a whole code for download at the end of the this post:

Loop:

```
function sequencedFade(imgIndex, numImages) {           
if(imgIndex < numImages) {
    /* =| Original method |=*/
    $("#btn"+imgIndex).animate({ backgroundColor: "#ff8888" }, "slow").delay(3000);
    $("#btn"+imgIndex).animate({ backgroundColor: "#8888ff" }, "slow");
    $("#"+imgIndex+"slika").fadeIn("slow").delay(3000);
    $("#"+imgIndex+"slika").fadeOut("slow", function() { sequencedFade(imgIndex+1, numImages)});
    }
else{
    $("#btn"+imgIndex).animate({ backgroundColor: "#ff8888" }, "slow").delay(3000);
    $("#btn"+imgIndex).animate({ backgroundColor: "#8888ff" }, "slow");
    $("#"+imgIndex+"slika").fadeIn("slow").delay(3000);
    $("#"+imgIndex+"slika").fadeOut("slow", function() { sequencedFade(1, numImages)});
    }
}
```

My "click" ideas that are not working so far:

```
$("#btn1").click(function(){

    $("#btn1").queue(function(){

        // 2xclick stops everything and maybe some other errors
        $(".gImages").stop(true,true).hide();
        $(".tBut").stop(true,true).animate({ backgroundColor: "#8888ff" }, 0);
        $(this).animate({ backgroundColor: "#ff8888" }, "slow").delay(3000);
        $(this).animate({ backgroundColor: "#8888ff" }, "slow");
        $(this).dequeue();
        /* delay works but 2 instances of loop are sown on 3 clicks
        $(this).queue(function(){
            $(this).animate({ backgroundColor: "#ff8888" }, "slow").delay(3000);
            $(this).animate({ backgroundColor: "#8888ff" }, "slow");
            $(this).dequeue();
            });
    */
    });

$("#1slika").queue(function(){
    $(this).fadeIn("slow").delay(3000);
    $(this).fadeOut("slow",function(){
        sequencedFade(2,4);
        });
    $(this).dequeue();
        });

    /* ======| a lot of glitches |===== 
    $("fx").clearQueue();
    $("fx").stop(true);
    $(".gImages").stop(true,true).hide();
    $(".tBut").stop(true,true).animate({ backgroundColor: "#8888ff" }, 0);
    sequencedFade(1,4);
    */
    });
```

[Download whole project](http://www.mediafire.com/?m6736cjod5ddx6x)

Comment: Please isolate the issue as much as possible and post the code on a site like http://jsfiddle.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works for me

Hope it will help you ))

```
var numOfimgs=4;
$(document).ready(function(){

function preloadImages(numOfimgs){
    var i;
    for(i=1; i<numOfimgs+1; i++){
        $("div#ldAr").append('<img class="gImages" id="'+i+'slika" src="'+i+'.jpg" />');
        $("img#"+i+"slika").hide();
        //$("div#ldAr").append(i);
    }
}

preloadImages(numOfimgs);

$('.tBut').live('click',function(){
    var i = $(this).index()+1;
    $('.gImages').hide();
    $('.tBut').animate({ backgroundColor: "#8888ff" }, "slow");
    $(this).animate({ backgroundColor: "#ff8888" }, 500);
    $('#ldAr').html('');
    preloadImages(numOfimgs);
    sequencedFade(i, numOfimgs)
})

function sequencedFade(imgIndex, numImages) {

    /* =| Original method |=*/
    $("#btn"+imgIndex).animate({ backgroundColor: "#ff8888" }, "slow");

    $("#"+imgIndex+"slika").fadeIn("slow").delay(3000);
    $("#"+imgIndex+"slika").fadeOut("slow", function() { 
    $("#btn"+imgIndex).animate({ backgroundColor: "#8888ff" }, "slow"); 
        imgIndex < numImages ? sequencedFade(imgIndex+1, numImages) : sequencedFade(1, numImages)
    });
}

sequencedFade(1,4);

});
```

Comment: Wow, I guess less is more hehe ...so much better. Thank you.

hmm I'm not sure I understand it all so I'll write what I think it might be and when and if you have time correct me.

so you removed all unnecessary things, added something like an event handler with "live()" (didn't covered "live()" and "index()" yet so I'm guessing here) for click events. 

hmm.. used "index()" to get position index of the current element with  ".tBut" class and "i" as a carrier for the next element in order to easier pass as the argument

fadedOut all and fadedIn current button

cleaned "#ldAr" (loader div)

Comment: preloaded images again and called for the sequencedFade for next button and image.

So please correct me where I understood wron. Thank you.